# How to customise message on drupal

Tags: drupal-7

i want to customize the message and I'd like to know if it is possible to do it without coding [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa1kW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Drupal module [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) to **replace** this text. If you want to **translate** the text you should use the Locale module which enables the translation of the user interface to languages other than English. Locale is a Drupal Core module.